# Issue with negative top, causing spacing issue with div's below

Tags: css

So I have following css on a div

.hdrContainer       { position: relative; top: -28px; left: 0; z-index: 1001; background-repeat:no-repeat;padding-top: 35px;}

Where I added the negative top margin, and padding top margin. The reason for this was to get the background image of this div to the top of the page and the push the content down so it appears correctly in the div. And this looks fine.

The issue is that it has causing spacing between the div below this where there was no spacing before. Which has the following simple css.

```
.container { margin: 0 auto; text-align: left; width: 980px; }
```

So the markup is as follows

```
<div class="hdrContainer">...</div>
<div class="container">...</>
```

And adding the negative top has caused spacing between these div's for some reason.

Any Ideas, how I can remove anything below .hrdContainer to be not affected by changes above ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `top:-28px` to `margin-top: -28px` and you're good to go.

http://jsfiddle.net/VeR3S/